# Watir WebDriver: undefined method 'alert'

Tags: javascript, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I try to use Cucumber with help from watir webdriver with JavaScript.

If I tip: browser.alert.exists? 
I become: undefined method 'alert'

What must I doing, if I will this commands to use: http://watirwebdriver.com/javascript-dialogs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alert API you refer to is only very new and in the latest version of watir-webdriver.

You should update to the latest watir-webdriver gem:

```
gem update watir-webdriver
```